# Make sidebar scroll with locked header?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the left purple content scroll like the middle and right panels (see snippet)?
I assume there is something I'm missing to add in `.Left-container` in the css?

```css
/*I love me some border-box*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*This just stops me getting horizontal scrolling if anything overflows the width*/
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*Just removing default browser padding/margin*/
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ebebeb;
}
/*Flexbox gives us the flexiness we need. The top just stays put as there is no scrolling on the body due to the page never exceeding viewport height*/
.Top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    font-size: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
}
/*This is our main wrapping element, it's made 100vh high to ensure it is always the correct size and then moved into place and padded with negative margin and padding*/
.Container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: overflow;
}
/*All the scrollable sections should overflow and be whatever height they need to be. As they are flex-items (due to being inside a flex container) they could be made to stretch full height at all times if needed.
WebKit inertia scrolling is being added here for any present/future devices that are able to make use of it.
*/
.Left,
.Middle,
.Right {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: .5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
/*Entirely optional – just wanted to remove the scrollbar on WebKit browsers as I find them ugly*/
.Left::-webkit-scrollbar,
.Middle::-webkit-scrollbar,
.Right::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
/*  Left and Right are set sizes while the Middle is set to flex one so it occupies all remaining space. This could be set as a width too if prefereable, perhaps using calc.*/
.Left {
    width: 12.5rem;
    background-color: indigo;
}

.Middle {
    flex: 1;
}

.Right {
    width: 12.5rem;
    background-color: violet;
}

.locked-header {
  background: black;
}

.Left-container {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Independent CSS scrolling panels (with inertia)</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="Top">Top Content</div>
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Left-container"><div class="locked-header">Locked header should stay</div><div class="Left">Left Content should scroll like right side...<br /><br /> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div>
        <div class="Middle">Middle Content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Eariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, </div>
        <div class="Right">Right Content tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Exce dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you should take a look at stickykit.js. it does what you need

Comment: @Manjunath Would prefer a css solution and where the boxes are scrolling independently. stickykit.js doesn't seem to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `max-height` using `calc` in `.Left`. I  have commented `Added CSS` in the code

```css
/*I love me some border-box*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*This just stops me getting horizontal scrolling if anything overflows the width*/
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*Just removing default browser padding/margin*/
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ebebeb;
}
/*Flexbox gives us the flexiness we need. The top just stays put as there is no scrolling on the body due to the page never exceeding viewport height*/
.Top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    font-size: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
}
/*This is our main wrapping element, it's made 100vh high to ensure it is always the correct size and then moved into place and padded with negative margin and padding*/
.Container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: overflow;
}
/*All the scrollable sections should overflow and be whatever height they need to be. As they are flex-items (due to being inside a flex container) they could be made to stretch full height at all times if needed.
WebKit inertia scrolling is being added here for any present/future devices that are able to make use of it.
*/
.Left,
.Middle,
.Right {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: .5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
/*Entirely optional – just wanted to remove the scrollbar on WebKit browsers as I find them ugly*/
.Left::-webkit-scrollbar,
.Middle::-webkit-scrollbar,
.Right::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
/*  Left and Right are set sizes while the Middle is set to flex one so it occupies all remaining space. This could be set as a width too if prefereable, perhaps using calc.*/
.Left {
    width: 12.5rem;
    background-color: indigo;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 117px); /* Added CSS */
}

.Middle {
    flex: 1;
}

.Right {
    width: 12.5rem;
    background-color: violet;
}

.locked-header {
  background: black;
}

.Left-container {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Independent CSS scrolling panels (with inertia)</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="Top">Top Content</div>
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Left-container"><div class="locked-header">Locked header should stay</div><div class="Left">Left Content should scroll like right side...<br /><br /> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div>
        <div class="Middle">Middle Content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Eariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, </div>
        <div class="Right">Right Content tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Exce dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Working fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qwgse9rz/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Quick question. Where did you get 117px from? Trial and error? Any way to make it all non-sensitive to fixed values?

Comment: @SeaBass it is the total height of `Top` and `locked-header`